# Single Page Web-App Menu Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a single page web app frontend using Bootstrap. I have a menu on the side of the page and I want whichever item is selected to be highlighted.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
  <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li><a href="#">Get Snippet</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Tags</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Rules</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Macros</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">History</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Performance</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I did some searching around online as to how to do this, but I only found resources which implemented a solution using separate .html pages for each menu item. Is there a way to do this using JavaScript and only the current active .html page?

Here's a jS snippet that I tried, but it fails to deselect the other items:

```
<script>
  var menuArr = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var prevLI = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < menuArr.length; i++) {
    menuArr[i].onclick = function() {
      if (prevLI != "" && prevLI != this) {
        prevLI.className = "";
      }
      this.className = "active";
      prevLI = this;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Just added some jS :)

Comment: I would remove the active class from all nav list items and then reapply the class back to the one clicked. Sorry I'm not near my comp or I'd show an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey i have created an example on jsfiddle using your code:-

```
 var menuArr = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
 var prevLI = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
 if (prevLI)
     prevLI = prevLI[0];
 for (var i = 0; i < menuArr.length; i++) {
     menuArr[i].onclick = function() {
         if (prevLI != "" && prevLI != this) {

             prevLI.className = "";
         }
         this.className = "active";
         prevLI = this;
     }
 }
```

working example:http://jsfiddle.net/BtkCf/163/

thanks

Comment: I cannot loop the `menuArr` although my script gets loaded after the Html code.I get a `live` `HTMLCollection` from `elementsbyclassname()`.